How can i optimize these repetitive if with queryselectors inside?
i need to simplify these lines of code of react, i see is a bit repetitive, but i dont know if theres any way to improve this
Any idea will be received!!!
useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      // Prices
      if(document.querySelector("#prices").getBoundingClientRect().top == 78){
        document.querySelector(".pricesArr").style.opacity = 1
        document.querySelector(".pricesArr").classList.add("pricesArrAnim")
      }
      else if(document.querySelector("#prices").getBoundingClientRect().top > 660){
        document.querySelector(".pricesArr").style.opacity = 0
        document.querySelector(".pricesArr").classList.remove("pricesArrAnim")
      }
      // Contact
      if(document.querySelector("#contact").getBoundingClientRect().top == 78){
        document.querySelector(".contact").style.opacity = 1
        document.querySelector(".contact").classList.add("contactAnim")
      }
      else if(document.querySelector("#contact").getBoundingClientRect().top > 660){
        document.querySelector(".contact").style.opacity = 0
        document.querySelector(".contact").classList.remove("contactAnim")
      }
      // Moreinfo
      if(document.querySelector("#moreinfo").getBoundingClientRect().top == 78){
        document.querySelector(".moreinfo").style.opacity = 1
        document.querySelector(".moreinfo").classList.add("moreinfoAnim")
      }
      else if(document.querySelector("#moreinfo").getBoundingClientRect().top > 660){
        document.querySelector(".moreinfo").style.opacity = 0
        document.querySelector(".moreinfo").classList.remove("moreinfoAnim")
      }
    })
  })


Something like this would do the trick, just adjust your classNames a bit to match id/class selectors.
const determineVisibility = useCallback(selector => {    
    const boundaries = {
        visible: 78,
        transparent: 660
    }

    const elemToCheck = document.getElementById(selector);
    const elemToModify = document.querySelector("." + selector);
    const {top} = elemToCheck.getBoundingClientRect();
    
    if(top == boundaries.visible){
        elemToModify.style.opacity = 1
        elemToModify.classList.add(selector + "Anim")
    } else if(top > boundaries.transparent){
        elemToModify.style.opacity = 0
        elemToModify.classList.remove(selector + "Anim")
    }
}, [])    

useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {    
        ["prices", "contact", "moreinfo"].forEach(determineVisibility)    
    })
}, [determineVisibility])

Also, I would suggest you no to run this function from the anonynmous event handler, it makes it problematic to cleanup the listener in the future.

thanks!! this works, sorry but i know the existence of useCallback, but i dont know how it works, but thanks!!

You are welcome. useCallback just tells React to remember the function you pass to it for the next rerenders. In this case it will remember it forever since the dependency array in the end is empty. This is needed because useEffect depends on that function, and if it's not memoised, the effect will rerun on every component rerender.
You can avoid using useCallback if you move the determineVisibility function into the effect itself. However, it will make it bulky.

Unless you plan on adding a whole bunch more then no need to prematurely optimise, nothing wrong with a few if else statements. But if you are going to be adding a bunch more cases, you can do something like this (not tested):
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    const select = document.querySelector;
    [
      { idEl: select("#prices"), classEl: select(".pricesArr"), newClass: "pricesArrAnim" },
      { idEl: select("#contact"), classEl: select(".contact"), newClass: "contactAnim" },
      { idEl: select("#moreinfo"), classEl: select(".moreinfo"), newClass: "moreinfoAnim" }
    ].forEach(obj => {
      if(obj.idEl.getBoundingClientRect().top == 78){
        obj.classEl.style.opacity = 1
        obj.classEl.classList.add(obj.newClass)
      }
      else if(obj.idEl.getBoundingClientRect().top > 660){
        obj.classEl.style.opacity = 0
        obj.classEl.classList.remove(obj.newClass)
      }
    });

  })
})

So in this case, if you wanted to add another case you just add another object to the array with the idEl, classEl and newClass you need and it'll do that too. One line to add another case.
